# HTML5 canvas: image resizing

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I'm trying to place an image on a canvas without resizing it. I thought drawImage(img, x, y) would do the trick, but it stretches the image to fill the canvas.
Also supplying drawImage(img, x, y, width, height) with the dimensions of my image doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
<canvas id="story" style="position:relative; width:800px; height:600px;"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("story");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("img1");
  var width = parseInt(img.width);
  var height = parseInt(img.height);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
}

</script>
<img id="img1" alt="" src="http://link to image"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: I added the parseInt's to make sure that drawImage gets valid values.

Comment: When I call `drawImage` (in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 9), it does not stretch to fill the canvas. Can you show us an example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) where this is happening?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't use CSS to size your canvas. That creates a default sized canvas and stretches it. Set the canvas dimensions directly on it and you'll get a 1 to 1 pixel drawing space.

```
<canvas id="story" width="800" height="600" style="position:relative;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! saved my Friday!

Comment: Thank you so much for this; I've been having such a headache trying to figure out why despite having correct source & destination dimensions set in drawImage(), the image would still be drawn out of proportion! I'd give you 100 upvotes on this answer if I could!

Answer (score 14):

Trochoid is right, the style attribute on your canvas tag is causing problems.  You could set it in the HTML, as he suggests, or better yet you can leave it blank and set it dynamically in the JS:

```
<canvas id="story"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("story");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var img = document.getElementById("img1");
      var width = parseInt(img.width);
      var height = parseInt(img.height);

      canvas.height=height;
      canvas.width=width;
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

</script>
<img id="img1" alt="" src="http://link to image"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure you get the width and height of the image and draw it AFTER it has been loaded.

```
img.onload = function () {
  var width = parseInt(img.width);
  var height = parseInt(img.height);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first load the function image perfectly before rendering on the screen to do that follow the below code..

```
<img id="demo-img" src="image_name.png">

<br>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag
</canvas>

<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("demo-img");
    img.onload=function fun(){ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,img.width,img.height)}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library I recently created which can load an image, resize it fixed width & height or precentage, convert to and from other formats like base64 or blob, and allows you to apply a watermark.

```
var CanvaWork = new CanvaWork();

CanvaWork.loadImage("yourimage.png", function(obj){
    console.log(obj.canvas);  // The usable canvas
    console.log(obj.width);
    console.log(obj.height);
    console.log(obj.image); // Contains the image file
});
```

https://github.com/vnbenny/canvawork.js

Hope this helps you!